# Cannot Access Windows 2012R2 Shares from Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows, network-share, server-message-block

I am having an odd issue that I hope someone can help with.  I have an older 32bit Windows Server 2003SP2 server that cannot access any shares on our 64bit Windows Server 2012R2 domain controller.  The 2003 server can access shares on other 2012R2 servers fine, it is just the one server it has problems with.  Also, the 2012R2 server can access shares on the 2003 server fine. There is no firewall or AV on the 2003 server but the 2012R2 server has both the firewall and Symantec Endpoint Protection installed on it.  No other clients have problems access the 2012R2 server (although all the other machines access it are Win10/Win2012R2).

I have checked the event log on both machines and there are no messages.  If I try and access a share with Windows Explorer, I get the error "Windows cannot find '\win2012R2\sharename'. Check the spelling and try again, or try searching for the item by clicking the Start button and then clicking search."  If I try from the command line using NET USE, I get the error "System error 64 has occurred.  The specified network name is no longer available".  I can ping the 2012R2 server from the 2003 server fine.  DNS lookups also work fine.

Is there some sort of SMB access logging I can look at?

EDIT:

I installed Wireshark and recorded the following traffic when from the 2003 server when trying to connect to the 2012R2 server:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6361 79.400489000   2003srvr.domainname.lcl 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl TCP      62     12575->netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 6361: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5), Dst: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10), Dst: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 12575 (12575), Dst Port: netbios-ssn (139), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6363 79.400812000   2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl 2003srvr.domainname.lcl TCP      62     netbios-ssn->12575 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 6363: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04), Dst: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6), Dst: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: netbios-ssn (139), Dst Port: 12575 (12575), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6364 79.400822000   2003srvr.domainname.lcl 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl TCP      54     12575->netbios-ssn [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0

Frame 6364: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5), Dst: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10), Dst: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 12575 (12575), Dst Port: netbios-ssn (139), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6366 79.400881000   2003srvr.domainname.lcl 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl NBSS     126    Session request, to 2012R2SRVR<20> from 2003SRVR<00>

Frame 6366: 126 bytes on wire (1008 bits), 126 bytes captured (1008 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5), Dst: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10), Dst: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 12575 (12575), Dst Port: netbios-ssn (139), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 72
NetBIOS Session Service

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6368 79.401133000   2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl 2003srvr.domainname.lcl NBSS     60     Positive session response

Frame 6368: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04), Dst: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6), Dst: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: netbios-ssn (139), Dst Port: 12575 (12575), Seq: 1, Ack: 73, Len: 4
NetBIOS Session Service

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6369 79.401226000   2003srvr.domainname.lcl 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl SMB      191    Negotiate Protocol Request

Frame 6369: 191 bytes on wire (1528 bits), 191 bytes captured (1528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5), Dst: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10), Dst: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 12575 (12575), Dst Port: netbios-ssn (139), Seq: 73, Ack: 5, Len: 137
NetBIOS Session Service
SMB (Server Message Block Protocol)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   6371 79.401507000   2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl 2003srvr.domainname.lcl TCP      60     netbios-ssn->12575 [RST, ACK] Seq=5 Ack=210 Win=0 Len=0

Frame 6371: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 192.168.112.6 (ff:ff:ff:9b:08:04), Dst: Vmware_9b:7e:e5 (ff:ff:ff:9b:7e:e5)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2012r2srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.6), Dst: 2003srvr.domainname.lcl (192.168.112.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: netbios-ssn (139), Dst Port: 12575 (12575), Seq: 5, Ack: 210, Len: 0
```

Maybe someone with more SMB knowledge can help but it looks like the 2003 server is closing the connection after trying to negotiate the protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close out this question with what ended up happening.  I never could get it working but we ended up disabling SMBv1 across the enterprise and decommissioning the 2003 server shortly there after.

Answer (score 2):

This does sound like a possible SMB issue. Yes there is SMB logging. You want to look in Event Viewer on both file servers and filter by Event ID. There are five Event IDs related to SMB. The Event IDs are 2011 2022 2504 2505 and 2506.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364961(v=ws.10).aspx

You should make sure that you have a common version of SMB enabled (in your case  you need SMB1 enabled because you are using a Windows Server 2003 platform).

You can change the version of SMB the server uses in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters by setting the value data to "0" (disable) or "1" (enable) for the value name SMB1 or SMB2.

Your Wireshark logs appear to indicate the two servers are not able to negotiate a common SMB version. If that is the cause then enabling SMB1 on the 2012 server should get things working.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1,-smbv2,-and-smbv3-in-windows-vista,-windows-server-2008,-windows-7,-windows-server-2008-r2,-windows-8,-and-windows-server-2012

Comment: I looked on both servers for those event IDs and did not find any messages.  On the 2012R2 server I also looked in the Applications and Service Logs\Microsoft\Windows\SMBClient and SMBServer logs and didn't see anything from the 2003 server.

Comment: What version of SMB are you running on each server?

Comment: Server 2003 would be running SMB v1 and Server 2012R2 would be running SMB v3.  I haven't specifically set an SMB version so they should be the defaults.  If this is something that you can change then I would need to know where to go and look for it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I was sure this would be it but unfortunately, no.  SMB v1 is NOT disabled on my 2012R2 server.  Server 2003 only supports SMB V1 so there is nothing to enable/disable on that one.  They should both be able to talk using SMB V1.

Comment: I agree they _should_ be able to talk using SMB1. What happens if you try using Wireshark but doing a capture filter `port 139 || port 445`? Once you start Wireshark try to access the other server and then what does it tell you?

Comment: That is what you are seeing above.  I filtered the traffic only by src/dst host IP addresses.  All traffic on all ports between the hosts should be shown.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You could try disabling SMB2 (not recommended). Please note if you make the change from the registry then you do need to restart the computer.

Comment: Ok.  I'll have to try this after hours as this is our active file server and I don't want to mess up other users.

Comment: Well, that didn't work either.  Same error.  The 2003 server is going to get replaced in a few months so maybe I'll just ignore it for now.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365236(v=vs.85).aspx) is an example of the SMB communication for each device. You might also want to check your registry settings to make sure the data for `lmcompatibilitylevel` is correct. The article with that information is [https://richardkok.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/wireshark-determining-a-smb-and-ntlm-version-in-a-windows-environment/](https://richardkok.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/wireshark-determining-a-smb-and-ntlm-version-in-a-windows-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but the problem can be with NTLM settings in Group Policy. You can modify your policy settings to enable NTLM v1 and NTLM v2, so Win 2003 can see the shares.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c2d7342-201c-439a-9c71-3fcdaade51af/windows-7-cant-access-a-shared-folder-on-server-2003-but-pc-with-xp-can?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: I thought it might be something like this but the 2003 server can access any of the other 2012R2 servers we have installed (including other domain controllers).  It is just this one specific server it has problems with.  If it was a group policy thing it would affect at least all other domain controllers as we don't have any group policies that affect the one 2012R2 server I can't connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, except a Win10 client could not access a Win2003 server. I did not have event log messages either. However, executing `NET USE \\<servername>\<sharename>` from an admin command window from the client resulted in an informative error message stating SMBv1 is required but not available. SMB will auto-negotiate to a compatible level, but SMBv1 has security flaws, so has been disabled on some Windows versions, and not available in others. Windows Server 2003 only goes up to SMBv1, so if the the other machine doesn't have SMBv1 then the connection will fail. The accesser of the share, the client, only needs the client protocol, and the host only needs the server protocol. It can be enabled/disabled through Control Panel | Programs and Features | Turn Windows features on or off | SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support, if it is installed. It can also be enabled/disabled through a GPO, which might override Windows feature changes.

I would recommend enabling only what you have to, only for the duration that you have to. It was disabled for a reason (e.g. some ransomware attacks).

Comment: _Don't enable SMBv1._ It has fatal security flaws and is or should be being phased out everywhere. Win 2003 server is also past end-of-life, so the solution here is to upgrade Win 2003 server.